# Update Manager Not working

Tags: 11.10, update-manager

Hi When I try to press CHECK Button in Updated, it is not looking for updates available.

getting below error.

```
"Failed to Download repository information"

Check your Internet connection..

W:GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W:GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com lucid Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W:Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Ubuntu Version 11.10

Comment: may be you have the same problem as here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82700/i-tried-adding-the-gnome-3-ppa-but-now-get-error-failed-to-load-the-package-li/82756#82756

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try these in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Mark the answer as correct using the green check mark on it, regards.

Comment: Do you know how to make it work in Ubuntu 10.10....